# Is Holistic vs Subjective the same as Reductionist vs Objective?

Tags: ux-field

**User experience approaches**

In UX books i read about two approaches in ux: Reductionist and Holistic.
But some books also use Subjective and Objective.

Book: Modeling Users' Experiences with Interactive Systems. 
Defines two approaches in user experience research (**Reductionist and Holistic**).

Book:Experience Design (Hassenzahl). "Key properties of experience" is **subjective, holistic[...]**

His chapters are called : subjetive(versus objective), Holistic (versus instrumental.) (No reductionist??)

**Reductionist** : the reductionist approach contends that “complexity and richness 
of user experience[...] can be reduced to a set of manipulable and measurable variables”

**Holistic** : rooted in pragmatist philosophy. Criticize reductionist approaches in that they reduce the complexity and richness of user experience to a set of manipulable and measurable variables..

How to understand Objective/Subjective in relation to Reductionist and Holistic?

Comment: it would be nice to know which books are you talking about or even add some text here. At first glimpse, while similar, they're not the same. **Reductionism and Holism** are psychological concepts and as such, can be applied to UX, while *subjective* and *objective* are broad concepts that can be applied to anything. You can use a *reductionist* or *holistic* approach, and any of them can be *subjective* or *objective*. Very interesting question, though, too bad it has been closed

Comment: Reopened since the question is much more clear--I do agree with @Devin though, it could be useful to know the specific books and arguments you're referring to, to help build context.

Answer (score 1):

Holistic is not the same as subjective and objective is not the same as reductionist.

You could use a reductionist approach to observe subjective elements of the user experience. Alternatively you could use a holistic approach to gaining insight into the objective nature of an experience. Reductionism and Holism only relate to the context of the observed user experience - that is whether you look at behaviours in isolation or in context. Objective and Subjective approach vary in the type of information they seek to extract about an experience.

Objective relates to those properties of the user experience that can be reliably and repeatedly measured.

Subjective relates to those properties of the user experience that cannot be reliably and repeatedly measured - opinions, assumptions and things that are subject to an individuals background and unique situation.

Reductionist approaches aim to understand the user experience by observing user behaviours in isolation from other potentially relevant factors.

Holistic approaches aim to understand the user experience by observing user behaviours in more realistic contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think either terminology is that helpful and certainly those aren't the best words for it. And the two sets of terms don't semantically mean the same thing.

There are certainly aspects of detail (for which there are lots of UX 'rules'.)   And then there is the overall experience

And getting the detail right doesn't necessarily mean that the overall experience works.

It's to do with two levels of analysis: 'seeing the trees' (a reductionist approach) and 'seeing the forest' (a holistic approach).

Answer (score 0):

"Complexity and richness of user experience[...] can be reduced to a set of manipulable and measurable variables".

Measures and variables are objective. Which means, reductionist approach is about objective means of evaluating the UX.

If reductionism is an opposite thing to holism, then holistic approach is about subjective means of seeing the UX (for instance, subjective models of users' minds and empathy).

Thus, Holistic (subjective) approach is an opposite to the Reductive (objective) approach.